# Permission denied (publickey) on digtial ocean droplet

Tags: mysql, apache, ssh, digital-ocean

I recently tried to login to my droplet through ssh `ssh root@360productions.com` and am unable to gain any access to the server what so ever. The error I keep receiving `Permission denied (publickey).`

### I have tried the following.

1. Used `ssh-add` inside of the ssh directory to add `id_rsa` *no success*
2. Created new ssh key and performed `ssh-add` *no success*
3. Tried to copy over to server `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@360productions.com "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"` *no success*
4. Inside the settings of my account I changed the ssh values *no success*

I am thinking the issue has something to do with the droplet holding onto a public key that I don't have anymore on my machine. How can I gain access again to the server successfully through ssh?

When I run a debug i get this output. Trying to deceiver what's going wrong in here.

```
OpenSSH_7.5p1, LibreSSL 2.5.4
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 360productions.com [2604:a880:2:d0::45:a001] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/Basecamp/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Basecamp/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Basecamp/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Basecamp/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Basecamp/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Basecamp/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Basecamp/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Basecamp/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 360productions.com:22 as 'Basecamp'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:CI6GGFMyR17U6SoUOCwCMXBXc6JtxsuAxRX5Wdvt79Q
debug1: Host '360productions.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/Basecamp/.ssh/known_hosts:30
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/Basecamp/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Basecamp/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Basecamp/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Basecamp/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

How can I update the server with the correct public key?

Answer (score 4):

You should specify the private key with the ssh -i option.  For example:

```
ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa user@host.com
```

If your authorized keys doesn't have the corresponding public key, you can login via the Digital Ocean website.  There is a "Access" link that allows you to type in your password.  You can fix the authorized_keys file from there.

Again, you need to add the public key (id_rsa.pub) to authorized_keys on the server, and specify the private key (id_rsa) with the -i option to ssh.

You won't be able to ssh in order to append the new public key if another public key isn't already there and specified with -i.

Also, you may have to specify /root/.ssh/authorized_keys, I'm not sure that ~/.ssh will work with root.  Also verify the file is owned by root and has 600 permissions.

Comment: Thanks. I know I can gain access via the digital ocean console. Is that what you are referring to as the "Access Link" ?

Comment: @brent_white yeah, you can login and make sure authorized_keys is setup from there.  if password authentication is already disabled, that's the only way to add the public key to the authorized_keys, assuming you don't have another key already setup and working

Comment: when I enter `ssh -i /Users/Basecamp/.ssh/id_rsa root@360productions.com` I still get the refusal Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: @brent_white that probably means that the /Users/Basecamp/.ssh/id_rsa.pub has not been appended to the server's authorized_keys file.  Did you verify that the public key is already on the server?

Comment: where on the server will you find authorized_keys?

Comment: it would be /root/.ssh/authorized_keys for root or /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys for a user